# php redirect if domain name

Tags: php, redirect, dns

If read some post and write this code... but it isn´t working. I have 2 domains in the same hosting account. And I like to redirect visitors to a flash or WordPress site depending on which domain they use.
This is my code:

```
<?php 
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; 
if($host == 'elfarosociedades.com.ar' or $host == 'http://www.elfarosociedades.com.ar/' or $host == 'http://elfarosociedades.com.ar/' or $host == 'www.elfarosociedades.com.ar') {
header('Location: http://www.elfarosociedades.com.ar/index.php');
else 
header('Location: http://villarincondelsol.com.ar/home.html'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Print out the value of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and make sure it's what you expect. You probably want `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead.

Comment: thanks I{ve tried that also, and SELF, but nothing happened, are my ' ok? or there should be " ??

Comment: current also not working: `<?php 
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_HOST']; 
if($host == 'elfarosociedades.com.ar' or $host == 'http://www.elfarosociedades.com.ar/' or $host == 'http://elfarosociedades.com.ar/' or $host == 'www.elfarosociedades.com.ar') {
header('Location: http://www.elfarosociedades.com.ar/arg/index.php');
else 
header('Location: http://villarincondelsol.com.ar/home.html'); 
}
?>`

Comment: Again, print out `$host` and see what its value is. Chances are it's not what you expect. You may need to `exit` after the `header` calls, too. Stop making up non-existent things like `SERVER_HOST` randomly too.

Comment: It would be better to `stripos()` rather than defining every possible condition of the url.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php 
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 

$hosts=array(
    'elfarosociedades.com.ar' ,
    'http://www.elfarosociedades.com.ar/' , 
    'http://elfarosociedades.com.ar/' , 
    'www.elfarosociedades.com.ar' 
    );

if(in_array($host, $hosts)) {
    header('Location: http://www.elfarosociedades.com.ar/index.php');
 }else {
 header('Location: http://villarincondelsol.com.ar/home.html'); 
}
?>
```